# Implement calendar Class (System.Globalization) for an appointment in WebApi c#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have the entities `Customer` and `Dentist`. I would like to create a service, in C# and using a Web API, through which the customer can make an appointment.

More precisely, to make a `PUT`, through which a calendar will be displayed, to choose a date that he wants (depending on the availability of the `Dentist`), and thus to make a `PUT`.

I'm thinking that I need to implement `Calendar` class from `System.Globalization` but I don't know if it's the best choice. Could you help me with some tips, please?

I created a class `Appointment` like this:

```
public class Appointment 
{ 
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
    public DateTime Day { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString ="{0:hh:mm}")]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:hh:mm}")]
    public DateTime FinishTime { get; set; }

    public TimeSpan Duration => FinishTime - StartTime;

    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think you have to "implement a Calendar class"? What problem do you want to solve?

Comment: You don't need to implement the calender class. What makes you think that? Then you probably want to post not put and lastly I'd suggest to use `DateTimeOffset`.

Comment: Oh and since dentists don't tend to work night shifts, I guess a start DateTimeOffset and a duration TimeSpan will suffice for the request...